# Проверка коллизий между объектами

Tags: c#, unity3d

имеется два объекта (игрок и враг, находятся каждый на своем слое, висят коллайдеры и ригидбоди2Д, используется стандартная физика Юнити, игра в 2D). В настройках матрицы коллизий отключил между этими слоями столкновения, чтобы объекты могли проходить сквозь друг друга. Но как обычно бывает в 2Д играх, при прикосновении игрока с врагом нужно чтобы игрок получал урон и отлетал от врага. Далее включается кратковременная неуязвимость и персонаж может спокойно проходить между такими врагами (именно поэтому отключены столкновения). Так как в матрице коллизий столкновения отключены, такие события как OnCollisionEnter, OnTriggerEnter не срабатывают. В голове имеется мысль использовать Physics2D.OverlapCapsule (так как коллайдеры стоят капсульные на объектах) в апдейте или в фикседапдейте, но вот не знаю как это повлияет на производительность. В Юнити новичок, так что прошу тапками сильно не кидайте =) Если есть какие-то способы сделать это проще буду рад их услышать. Заранее спасибо =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У коллайдров есть возможность вести себя как триггеры. 
[Обзор коллайдров](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)
В этом режиме, они не создают препятствий, но по прежнему вызывают события физики OnTriggerEnter и прочее.

Comment: Но если я сделаю коллайдер-триггер, тогда ведь у меня просто враг будет проваливаться сквозь пол? Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Верно, здесь нужна более гибкая структура врага. Враг - пустой объект, в нем 2 подобъекта, Один отвечает за работу физики (нахождение на полу). Второй - урон. Из плюсов такого подхода , компонент урона может быть один для множества мест: враги ловушки итд.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень гибкий вариант получится, думаю то что надо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, если ответ подходит, отметьте его.

Answer (score 1):

Самым легким решением в плане производительности будет использование [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html). Производя Raycast, вы можете указать маску физических слоев, на которые будет реагировать луч. В Вашем случае их наверно придется отбрасывать несколько в разные стороны (но это не сильно скажется на производительности).

Comment: Про рейкасты знаю, знаю что очень дешевая операция в плане производительности, но всё равно интересно узнать, Physics2D.Overlap намного "тяжелее" ?

Comment: Можно чисто математически прикинуть. Посчитать пересечение луча (raycast) и коллаидра намного проще (с точки зрения мат. действий) чем пересечение двух геометрических фигур (например двух капсул)